# Why is my code not recognising a function declared above?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am having some trouble with method calls in Scala.

I am trying to use a pattern-matching approach to create an algorithm for the Shunting Yard problem. I have declared a function at the begining of my class that determines if a token is an operator or not. I then try to call this in the function for returning the reverse polish notation of an equation, however, I get the error:

```
error: not found: value operatorTrue
```

This is how my code looks:

```
def operatorTrue(val : String) : Boolean = {
    * Code for function
}



def foo(* arguments...) : Toks = {
    * Code not relevant to the question

        el match{
            case operatorTrue(el) => ...
        }
}
```

So the error is telling me that the issue lies at "operatorTrue(el) => ...". Why is this? I am confused because I declared the function already.

Comment: `operatorTrue` is not a valid case of **pattern matching**, you want to use an [**extractor**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html). Or you may `case x if operatorTrue(x) =>`.

Answer (score 1):

A function cannot be used as-is in pattern matching, it needs to be properly defined as extractor (cf `unapply`).

```
object OpTrue {
  def unapply(s: String): Boolean = ???
}

def foo(s: String) = s match {
  case OpTrue() => ??? // ~> if (OpTrue.unapply(s)) ...
}
```